# GroupBy Function NOT displaying Gallery Tiles in PowerApps

Tags: filter, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

This Question is an Extension of my previous question, located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580098/how-to-get-distinct-gallery-tiles-in-powerapps). When I use the `Filter` code mention in my Question. The Gallery is displaying System Names. However, when I try to wrap my `Filter` code with Groypby Function as mention by @carlosfigueira, I am NOT getting any Error message. However, I cannot see Gallery Tiles. Gallery is displaying lines as shown in below image. The code I am using under Items Property of my Gallery is below.

**Code for GroupBy:**

```
   GroupBy(
        Filter(Table1, StartsWith('Sys Name',"Sys")),
        "Sys_x0020_Name",
        "BySys")
```

**Gallery Screen:**
[image]

Comment: What other components do you have in your gallery? If there is a label, what's in the Text property?

Comment: @MuriloSantana.. The other components are Model and Previous Status. Their Text property is set to ThisItem.Model and ThisItem.'Previous Status' respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` function returns set of records whereas the text labels expect a `Text` input due to which you don't see the values in the gallery control.

You can add another gallery (Gallery2) inside the parent gallery's item and bind it to `ThisItem.BySys` as the data source & set `Text` property inside Gallery2 as `ThisItem.ColumnName1`. ColumnName1 would be the column from `Table1` collection.